# RANK() SQL Server execution plan issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

What is driving SQL Server to use less optimal execution plan for queries where 6000+ rows are returned? I need to improve query performance for scenario where all rows are returned.

I select all fields and add rank over same three columns included in index. Depending on number of returned rows, query has two different execution plans, hence execution takes 0.2s or 3s respectively.

From 1 row returned up to ca. 5000 query runs fast. From 6000 rows returned up to all, query runs slow.

`Table1` has ca. 38000 rows. Database runs on Azure SQL v12.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [KOD_ID] [int] NULL,
    [SYM] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [AN] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [A] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [B] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [C] [datetime] NULL,
    [D] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table1] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [KOD_ID] ASC,
    [SYM] ASC,
    [AN] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Queries:

```
SELECT TOP 6000 *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY KOD_ID ASC, SYM ASC, AN ASC) AS Rank#
FROM [dbo].[Table1]

SELECT TOP 7000 *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY KOD_ID ASC, SYM ASC, AN ASC) AS Rank#
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

Execution plans for both queries

[image: Execution plans]

Comment: Is the `*` necessary? This prohibits the use of a covering index, pushing the optimizer into a plan that simply scans the clustered index and sorts the whole table first because it thinks the nonclustered index won't sufficiently reduce I/O (and apparently, as it turns out, sorting takes even more time). Try adding `ORDER BY KOD_ID ASC, SYM ASC, AN ASC` to the query as a whole, this may tip the balance in favor of the index again.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Absolutely not necessary. I have replaced * with explicit column names, but this has not helped.

Comment: That's not what I meant, I meant whether or not you really needed *all* columns. `*` versus spelling them out makes no difference (performance-wise).

Comment: In theory, bookmark lookups can be forced by joining on a subquery: `SELECT TOP(7000) T.*, T1.Rank# FROM (SELECT TOP(7000) ID, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY KOD_ID ASC, SYM ASC, AN ASC) AS Rank# FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID) T JOIN Table1 ON T.ID = Table1.ID`. This is fairly hacky even if it works, though, since it prevents the optimizer from doing a single table scan even where that really is the best approach. Reclustering your table (as presented in the answer) is another promising approach.

Comment: @JeroenMostert TOP clause was used only to find out and demonstrate change in performance. Real-life requirement is to return all rows, so joining works perfectly. And this is how I have finally done it. I join remaining columns with the rank subquery `SELECT ID, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY KOD_ID ASC, SYM ASC, AN ASC) AS Rank# FROM [dbo].[Table1]` on ID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table1] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [KOD_ID] ASC,
    [SYM] ASC,
    [AN] ASC
) INCLUDE ([A], [B], [C], [D]);
```

Create such kind of a covering index and it should scan this index and most likely sort won't even be needed because it's data is already sorted in index.

The key points in your queries are:

1. First plan has a key lookup, avoid them as much as possible (key lookup is additional scan for each row because index does not have them) create covering indexes with INCLUDED columns
2. Avoid sort operations too, they're costly to SQL Server

If you're alright with index rebuilds and favor reads over inserts, these could be alternate DDLs for your table considering that  and `KOD_ID`, `SYM`, `AN` are not null-able:

If `ID` is needed to ensure uniqueness:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [KOD_ID] [int] NOT NULL
    , [SYM] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL
    , [AN] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL
    , [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    , [A] [nvarchar](10) NULL
    , [B] [nvarchar](2) NULL
    , [C] [datetime2] NULL
    , [D] [datetime2] NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KOD_ID], [SYM], [AN], [ID])
    );
GO
```

If `ID` is not needed to ensure uniqueness:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [KOD_ID] [int] NOT NULL
    , [SYM] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL
    , [AN] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL
    , [A] [nvarchar](10) NULL
    , [B] [nvarchar](2) NULL
    , [C] [datetime2] NULL
    , [D] [datetime2] NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KOD_ID], [SYM], [AN])
    );
GO
```

Also, note that I use `datetime2` instead of `datetime`, that's what Microsoft recommends: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql

> Use the **time**, **date**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** data
>   types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are
>   more portable. **time**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** provide
>   more seconds precision. **datetimeoffset** provides time zone support
>   for globally deployed applications.

Comment: While this will certainly cover the query, it essentially duplicates the whole table. This means all inserts an updates become more expensive, so care must be taken that this performance does not overly suffer.

Comment: Right, so you should just make that the clustered index.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: that's also not necessarily true, as presently, the clindex is an `IDENTITY`. This is good for serialized inserts; making the clustered index on columns that are not in order as they are inserted can cause serious index fragmentation, hurting all other queries as well. (But it's certainly worth considering, as opposed to the alternative of storing all data twice.)

Comment: Well, in the end it depends what OP needs, either these are inserts or reads. If these IDs are meaningless and I'll never run a query by that primary key - I'd better create a clustered index that will benefit my read queries.

Comment: The second alternative is almost certainly not meaningful since, if `KOD_ID`, `SYM` and `AN`  are unique, `RANK()` has no ties and the simpler `ROW_NUMBER()` could be used. Note that the primary key need not be the clustered index and the clustered index need not be unique; you could have `ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED` and `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ... (KOD_ID, SYM, AN)`. The resulting index will be smaller to boot (though the total space would only be reduced if you discarded the primary key altogether).

Comment: I've seen people use rank instead of row number for no apparent reason, and I've clearly stated why I removed id field, like I've said, it's just alternatives that could be used. It would be easier to give an advice if i knew data ☺️

Comment: `KOD_ID`, `SYM` and `AN` are not unique so this is the reason for additional `ID` (primary key) column and for `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Finally I have joined additional columns needed `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` with the rank subquery `SELECT ID, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY KOD_ID ASC, SYM ASC, AN ASC) AS Rank# FROM [dbo].[Table1]` on `ID` column. I have replaced `RANK()` with `DENSE_RANK()` so the numbers returned do not have gaps and always have consecutive ranks.